# CSS / less files not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, less, stylesheet

I have an issue on my [site](http://beta.fray.it) where suddenly the styling seems to be turned off...I have not removed any link to the stylesheet files, yet it seems as if they are not loaed. How would you fix this issue?

I noticed through Chrome that I get an uncaught reference error about an infinite_scroll not being defined, however I deactivated this plugin through the wordpress dashboard and I saw no effect.

Comment: This stylesheet is empty: http://beta.fray.it/wp-content/themes/fray/style.css

Comment: I know, I think they use the less file for styling....I dont know at all though what this less file does/alters

Comment: do you think that this empty css file interferes?

Comment: hmmm...removed it but saw no difference

Comment: To use .less file for styling you need to compile it into a .css file. So don't include .less like a regular stylesheet, but include style.css, which has to be generated by a LESS preprocessor.

Comment: Your source style.less file has a syntax error in `.inboxReminder {}`, there's `#position:absolute;`. Remove the hash and it compiles.

Comment: that was it, how can I reward you?

Comment: I've posted my comments as an answer so you could accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use .less file for styling you need to compile it into a .css file. So don't include .less like a regular stylesheet, but include style.css, which has to be generated by a LESS preprocessor.

Your source style.less file has a syntax error in `.inboxReminder {}`, there's `#position:absolute;`. Remove the hash and it compiles. (You can comment out single lines in LESS using `//`).

Comment: so you're telling me that whoever included the less file in there followed the wrong approach? it does seem to work now though

Comment: @KonstantinosPapakonstantinou yes, the browser doesn't know what to do with these files as it doesn't understand LESS syntax. You can use them in combination with less.js (a script that does the compilation in the browser) for development purposes, but in production you should only include the generated .css files. I see the style.css is still empty, so it's less.js copmpiling the files on the client side.